# Device mapping to container in docker lacks info

Tags: ubuntu, docker, virtual-machine

I have an Ubuntu VM with some virtual storage devices mounted and I want to map them to a docker container running there too. So I volumized the whole thing, mount points and also '/dev'. The devices do get recognized in the container, but for some reason `lsblk -o SERIAL` inside the container doesn't return anything, when in the VM it does. 
Also, running the python pyudev library functionality inside the container, I don't get the MODEL of the device either (in the VM I get the full info).

Anyone can shed light on why it happens?
Thanks!

Comment: Which kernel does that Ubuntu VM use? (https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12192)

Comment: can you show all the commands you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, found out that `smartctl` from `smartmontools` library solves the issue (`apt-get install smartmontools`). Returns both the MODEL and SERIAL of the devices, from inside the docker container, as opposed to `lsblk` and `lshw`.

As I was using python to query the devices for the info, the appropriate wrapper library for `smartctl` is `pySMART` (`pip install pySMART`). Works like a charm.